# How can an Excel XLL tell if a UDF is being called from the formula bar?

Tags: c++, excel, xll

I am looking for a way to determine inside my XLL whether the call is coming from the re-calculation process or from a new formula being entered for the cell. I have seen examples where the XLL can detect if it is being called from the Function Wizard (via checking the window class etc), but what if it is typed directly into the cell?

[image]

I can get the reference of the cell from the xlfCaller function:

```
   XLOPER xlRef;
   Excel(xlfCaller, &xlRef, 0);
```

but that doesn't get me very far. I am trying to mimic Excel's handling of the TODAY() function, which changes the cell number format if the formula is entered in the cell directly (rather than pasted or called from within another function).

Comment: `TODAY` is a volatile function. You can mark your functions as volatile when registering them, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation

Comment: Maybe you could use xlfCaller from a macro-equivalent function using deferred recalc to get the previous content of the cell and then see if it already contains a call to your function. But the function would suffer the consequences of being defined as macro-equivalent. see https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-8-getting-the-previously-calculated-value-from-the-calling-cells/ for some starting ideas.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams Thanks for that link. I will look into macro-equivalent!

Comment: @MadScientist I am not sure how making my function volatile would help me to determine the manner if which my function is being called?

Comment: From the documentation of xlfRegister: "On a worksheet, you can make a DLL function or code resource volatile, so that it recalculates every time the worksheet recalculates. To do this, add an exclamation mark (!) after the last argument code in the pxTypeText argument."

Comment: @MadScientist Volatility is not the issue. I am trying to hook into the process whereby Excel does different things depending on HOW a formula is entered into a cell. I am using TODAY as an example because in some circumstances Excel will change the number format of the cell to Date, and in others it does not. Try typing this into one cell: =TODAY()+1   , then type this formula into another cell: =2 * (TODAY()/2.0)   Do you see the difference in what is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to replicate this aspect of the TODAY() behaviour by hooking the SheetChange event - this will only fire when a formula is entered and not when it's recalculated (even with Ctrl-Alt-F9).  I don't know if TODAY() uses this approach or perhaps it uses something not available to user-defined functions.  In addition, replicating TODAY() would require parsing the formula and applying some logic to determine whether it applies the date format or not, this would be a bit tricky but there are some Excel formulas parsers out there.

In [xlOil](https://gitlab.com/stevecu/xloil) (disclaimer: I wrote it) it could be implemented as:

```
  XLO_FUNC_START(testToday())
  {
    CallerInfo caller;
    if (!caller.fullSheetName().empty()) // Check caller is worksheet
    {
      // Add a SheetChange handler
      auto handle = xloil::Event::SheetChange().bind(
        [=](const wchar_t* wsName, const Range& target)
        {
          // Need to check range here as well to avoid being triggered by another sheet change
          if (wsName == caller.sheetName())
            excelApp().Range[caller.writeAddress().c_str()]->NumberFormat = L"dd-mm-yyyy";
        }
      );
      // Wait 0.5 sec then unbind the event handler by queuing a window message with Excel
      auto milliSecsDelay = 500;
      excelPost([=]() mutable
      {
        handle.reset(); // Removes the SheetChange handler
      }, QueueType::WINDOW, 0, 0, milliSecsDelay);
    }

    // This is how to get the current date in C++
    std::tm buf; 
    auto now = std::time(0);
    localtime_s(&buf, &now);

    return returnValue(buf); // xlOil will convert the std::tm to an Excel date
  }
  XLO_FUNC_END(testToday);
```

This is just a proof-of-concept and could do with some tidying for example the range should be checked and the overhead could be quite large if the function was called many times.